# unexpected failure on unique constraint in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to load some data into neo4j from csv files, and it seems a unique constraint error is triggered when it shouldn't. In particular, I created a contraint using

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:`researcher`) ASSERT node.`id_patstats` IS UNIQUE;
```

Then, after inserting some data in neo4j, if I run (in *neo4j* browser)

```
MATCH (n:researcher {id_patstats: "2789"})
RETURN n
```

I get no results (*no changes, no records*), but if I run

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/manu/proyectos/PTL_RDIgraphs/rdigraphs/datamanager/tmp_patents/person906.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:researcher {`name` : line.`person_name`})
SET n.`id_patstats` = line.`person_id`;
```

I get

> Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed: Node(324016)
>   already exists with label `researcher` and property `id_patstats` =
>   '2789'

and the content of file `person906.csv` is

```
manu@cochi tmp_patents $cat person906.csv
person_id,person_name,doc_std_name,doc_std_name_id
2789,"li, jian",LI JIAN,2390
```

(this a minimum non working example extracted from a larger dataset; also, in the original "person906.csv" I made sure that "id_patstats" is really unique).

Any clue?

EDIT:

Still struggling with this...

If I run

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE EXISTS(n.id_patstats) 
RETURN DISTINCT "node" as entity, n.id_patstats AS id_patstats 
LIMIT 25 
UNION ALL 
MATCH ()-[r]-() 
WHERE EXISTS(r.id_patstats) 
RETURN DISTINCT "relationship" AS entity, r.id_patstats AS id_patstats 
LIMIT 25
```

(clicking in the neo4j browser to get some examples of the `id_patstats` property) I get

```
(no changes, no records)
```

that is, `id_patstats` property is not set anywhere. Moreover

```
MATCH (n:researcher {`name` : "li, jian"})
SET n.`id_patstats` = XXX;
```

this will always trigger an error regardless of *XXX*, which (I guess) means the actual problem is that the name "li, jian" is already present. Although I didn't set any constraint on the `name` property, I'm guessing neo4j goes like this: *you are trying to set a UNIQUE property on a node matching a property (name) that is not necessarily UNIQUE; hence that match could yield several nodes and I can't set the same UNIQUE property on all of them...so I won't even try*

Comment: Your realization at the end is correct. The unique constraint is getting violated because your MATCH to 'li, jian' matches to multiple nodes, and when you try to set the unique property key of all those nodes to the same value it violates your unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

At least two of your researchers have the same name. You shouldn't `MERGE` by name and then add id as a property. You should `MERGE` by id and add the name as a property and it will work fine.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/manu/proyectos/PTL_RDIgraphs/rdigraphs/datamanager/tmp_patents/person906.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:researcher {`id_patstats`:line.`person_id`})
SET n.name`=line.`person_name`;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong...but that's not the same thing, right? What I want is "if a `name` is already there, don't add the same `name` but update its properties"; what you wrote is "if an `id` is already there, update its `name` property". The latter could cause a name to be overwritten. In any case, I don't get the error (the response to the `MATCH` query says there is no `researcher` with that `id_patstats`, but the later error says there is)